# How to pass a List to a listview in a WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to fill a list view contained in a user control but I have hit a roadbloack and don't know how to continue.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="AC_Career_Mode.controls.HistoryTab"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AC_Career_Mode.controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="RecordsUC"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="RecordsCtrl_lv" SelectionMode="Single" Grid.Row="1" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Date" />
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="600" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Description"/>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Label Content="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="403" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My code behind

```cs
    public partial class HistoryTab : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Record> Records 
        { 
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Record>)GetValue(RecordsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RecordsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RecordsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Records", typeof(ObservableCollection<Record>),
                                                                                                            typeof(HistoryTab),
                                                                                                            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public HistoryTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }


    }
```

Then I'm invoking the uc like this

```
<uControl:HistoryTab x:Name="test_records" />
```

and trying to set the records property like this

```
test_records.Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(Record.DeserializeRecords(profile));
```

Now I don't know what else I have to do, I have googled and consulted many sources but either it's beyond my understanding giving little detail on what to do or too basic

Some links I visited

[Passing Generic lists to WPF usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062893/passing-generic-lists-to-a-wpf-usercontrol) (I don't know what the answer wants me to do)

[This youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UtFViownAA) (Good but strays away from what I want to do I think)

Comment: use `new PropertyMetadata(null)` instead of `new PropertyMetadata("")`. `""` is a string, and DP is defined with `ObservableCollection<Record>` type. therefore type mismatch

Comment: Well thanks yes that fixes the build error but I still can't get my list view filled, I'll edit the question so it's clearer

Comment: youtube tutorial clearly shows what else to do

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see it. The listbox is defined in the window xaml and then he is taking the selection to display one of the properties in the user control. Don't know how to translate that to what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like always, when you want to pass data to a control use data binding.
I recommend to read [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0) to get a quick idea about data binding.

You also should never set the `DataContext` of a custom control or `UserControl` to itself. This eliminates the chance to set a binding on the control's properties. Don't set the `DataContext` at all. It will be inherited or explicitly set in the context the control is used. This allows the following usage:

```xml
<!-- The HistoryTab.DataContext is implicitly inherited -->
<HistoryTab x:Name="test_records"
            Records="{Binding RecordItems}" />
```

`DataContext = this;` is only acceptable in a WPF root element like for example `Window`, `Page` and `Popup`. Because by definition these elements can't have a parent (in the visual tree), there won't be a parent data related context.

First fix the control's `DataContext`:

**HistoryTab.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class HistoryTab : UserControl
{
  public HistoryTab()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

Then bind the internal `ListView` to the parent's `Record` property:

```xml
<UserControl>
  <ListView x:Name="RecordsCtrl_lv" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Records}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this did it and now I understand UCs a bit better. I'll make sure to read about data binding as well